# .htaccess allows everyone once first successful login

Tags: apache, .htaccess, basic-authentication, .htpasswd

I'm trying to protect a single URI path. In the browser, it pops up the user / pass like normal. Once authenticated, any browser from any IP has access to that path. I'm not sure what I've got messed up.

/var/www/path/to/site/.htaccess:

```
<If "%{REQUEST_URI} =~ m#/protect-me/?#i">
    AuthUserFile /var/www/path/to/site/.htpassword
    AuthName "Password protected"
    AuthType Basic
    Require valid-user
</If>
```

mysite.conf:

```
<VirtualHost >
...
    <Directory /var/www/path/to/site/>
      Options -Indexes +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
      AllowOverride All
    </Directory>
...
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: _“Once authenticated, any browser from any IP has access to that path.”_ - can’t see that making sense in any way. There is no mechanism by which this could “disable” itself, and other clients should not magically start sending credentials (if they even got them), without being prompted to first.

Comment: This is so bizarre. HTTPD bug maybe?
1. I used Tor, Chrome, Firefox browser and get the p/w prompt.
2. Auth on any one of these browsers.
3. Refresh any other browser wouldn't prompt anymore.

Comment: This looks like a _fault_ with a server-side cache (ie. a front-end caching proxy - very typical of many configs). The cache is probably "bypassing" your application server. See this related question on the Webmasters stack: https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/136108/content-that-should-be-protected-is-served-without-authentication-intermittently

Comment: We do use varnish cache, but varnish is suppose to pass through. We ended up just going with a js solution.